# Use jQuery to find the child within this

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I got the slide up working thanks to help. I need it so that the .file-options will stay toggled until the mouse moves away from the .file div rather than from the .file img. You can see what happens here when you hover over the pdf image http://jsfiddle.net/5vAFh/

```
<div class="file">
    <a href="#"><img src="{$assets_url}img/file-icons/doc.png" alt=""></a>
    <div class="file-options showhouse-text">
        <a href="#" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file?');" class="show-tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Delete File"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="show-tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Edit File"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>


$('.file-options').hide();
$('.file img').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).closest('.file').find('.file-options').slideDown();
});
$('.file').mouseout(function(){
  $(this).find('.file-options').slideUp();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to traverse back up the tree. Find `file` first, then look for it's children:

```
$('.file-options').hide();
  $('.file img').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).closest(".file").find('.file-options').slideToggle();
    }, function() {
      $(this).closest(".file").find('.file-options').slideToggle();
    }
);
```

Or, if you know the DOM isn't going to change, get the parent `a`, then the parent `div`:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find(".file-options");
```

Comment: I had tried (this).parent.find('.file-options').slideToggle(); but that would have only taken me to < a > tag then, yeah?

Comment: Exactly, the parent of the `img` is actually the `<a>` tag. You need the parent of the parent. `Closest` finds the first match up the tree, so you don't need to chain loads of `parent()` calls

Comment: Ah problem, after i move down to the file-options they then slideToggle away. Need to change it to. If i hover over '.file img' it slide toggles but if I hover away from '.file' then it disappears

Comment: Any reason for using closest() rather than parent(".file")? Same with find() rather than first-child? I ask as I'm not sure which of these things is faster..

Comment: @Beagle90 See my above comment. `parent()` would return the `<a>` tag in which case we would need to use `siblings()` and `filter()` - too many calls. `closest()` / `find()` allows for future changes to DOM.

Comment: That's why I have put the .file selector in my parent call. I do see your point to allowing changes to the DOM; however as a counter point... I think parent() / first-child is more readable and explains a little better exactly what elements we're looking for?

Comment: @Beagle90 `.parent()` only finds direct parents, so even if you passed in a selector that wouldn't work. You wouldn't be able to find `.file-options` using first-child as it isn't the first child of any element.

Comment: @RGraham Hmm I'm sure I've used parent with selectors before. See the bottom example http://api.jquery.com/parent/ ? .file-options would be the first-child of parent(".file") I think.

Comment: You can pass in a selector, but it still only applies to direct parents. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/WTy2u/). `<a>` is the `first-child` of file. `.file-options` is the second child

Comment: @RGraham could you have a look at the revised question please? The toggle is working but when moving from the image to the icons the file options hide again. You can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/5vAFh/

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
    $('.file-options').hide();
      $('.file img').hover(
        function() {
          $(this).next('.file-options').slideToggle();
        }, function() {
          $(this).next('.file-options').slideToggle();
        }
    );
```